# Variable stage keeps coming back undefined

Tags: javascript, variables

Hi I am trying to get the result from function `test()` and use it to set variable `stageIs` however it keeps coming back `undefined`. Any help would be greatly appreciated I have been trying to figure it out for hours now.

```
var stage;
import { CONTRACT } from '../contract'
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      stageIs: null,
      amount: null
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.coinbase = CONTRACT._eth.coinbase
    this.test()
  },

  methods: {
    test () {
      CONTRACT.name1(function(err, res) {   
        stage = (res);      
      });
      alert(stage);
      this.stageIs= (stage)   
    }
```

When I do the alert inside the `test()` it works however it will not set `{{ stageIs }}` for some reason.

```
test () {
  CONTRACT.name1(function(err, res) {   
    stage = (res);
    alert(stage)
    this.stageIs = (stage)
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an anonymous function as an argument to `CONTRACT.name1`. By the signature of this anonymous function, `name1` seems to be asynchronous.

As a result, the call to `name1` will return immediately, while the work that is supposed to be done by `name1` will execute later in the event loop (or it is waiting for IO). As a result, `stage` would always be undefined.

What you want to do is this:

```
test () {
  let that = this;
  CONTRACT.name1(function(err, res) {   
    stage = (res);
    alert(stage)
    that.stageIs = stage;
  });
}
```

There are two things happening here. We are assigning a value to `stage` when the callback is invoked by the asynchronous function `name1`. We are also assigning a reference to `this` inside `test`, because the anonymous function will execute in a different context (and therefore the anonymous function's `this` would point to something else).

Or you could also use arrow functions to get rid of the `this` binding problem.

```
test () {
  CONTRACT.name1((err, res) => {   
    stage = (res);
    alert(stage)
    this.stageIs = stage;
  });
}
```

Comment: YOU SIR ARE MY HERO :). the name1 is a variable in an erc20 contract thank you :)